# giving a local json file for line chart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I want to create a line chart with some data from a json file, I'm working with Highcharts for that.

In the url for the json file I find something like that : `https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?`

I downloaded the json file and then I put it locally, when I give in the url the local json I dont see the chart.

How can I solve that ?

this is the full example in jsfiddle :

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/)

Comment: Please open the console and include a screenshot, also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript) question, I'm about 99% that this is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The data is in the format of .php you need to parse that into actual JSON by using json_encode or use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON along-with CORS and Using Apache as an internal server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a webserver, because browsers block run files from local file system, due to security reasons.